# VBA-Excel ComboBox having list of entries showing the last entered values first

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am trying to add names to the combo Box. I want to see the list of recently entered values first.
For example
Names
John
Sam
Smith
Will

I want to see the list in combo Box drop down as 
Will
Smith
Sam 
John

I tried using range function to set a range and then traverse the cells in the range and adding them to the comboBox.

Function Rangeform()
Set Rangeform = ActiveSheet.[a1:a50000]
End Function

For each cell in Rangeform
ComboBox8.AddItem cell
Next

Is there a way to set the range from last used row to the first and then looping backwards?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
'change Sheet1 to suit
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'backward loop
    For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        ComboBox8.AddItem .Range("A" & i)
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: It gives me a compilation error invalid or unqualified reference for .Range

Comment: try to use explicitly `ComboBox8.AddItem ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)` with correct sheet name instead `Sheet1`